# Binding triggered by property changed and by validation

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, binding

I've been using the .Net binding in Win Forms. I would like the bound property to be updated as soon as the user alters the value in the corresponding control. To achieve this I have set the Data Source Update Mode to OnPropertyChanged. Unfortunately, when i navigate away from the page the Focus Changed event causes Validation to occur again, which also causes the value to be set. Is there anyway to prevent this or work around it (other than setting the update mode to never) and pushing update manually?

Answer (score 0):

Seems i just needed to set CausesValidation to false on all the related controls